# flowers fade or fade away or fade off?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

What is the right word to use when we talk about withering flowers?
Is it faded or fade-off or fade away?

eg: The flowers faded-off/faded away/faded

Comment: fade away sounds rather poetic to me, dry up/wither

Comment: _Fade away_ suggests to me that something gradually disappears. Flowers fade, sounds fade away.

Answer (score 5):

The simple verb "fade" works well. It is slightly poetic.  There's no need for a phrasal verb.

Here is a recent example [from the BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-cambridgeshire-56145358)

> The delicate petals of the white flower, measuring 11ins (28cm) long by 6ins (15cm) wide and sitting at a height of 12ft (3.5m) on the plant, started to fade overnight.

"Fading" doesn't mean falling off or withering. It is the first stage of the flower starting to look old or tired.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that using "fade" to describe the wilting or withering of flowers is mostly to very poetic (as a native en_US speaker - I can't say that I've heard it used in UK English much either - regarding flowers, that is)

When I think of things that "fade" I immediately think of: colors, lights, fabrics, clothes, sunsets, images (especially in video - a fade to black or a fade out), pictures, ink... Also, haircuts. More morbidly, if someone is "fading away" ... they're usually dying.

For me at least, in general, "fade" has a sense of describing color or brightness. If you are describing the **effects** of wilting/withering on color, it sounds great ... (e.g. the flowers had wilted and their once bright colors had faded to a dull gray).

But if you're trying to describe that the flowers were no longer fresh in a general sense, I would use wilted.